# Can't use information from DynamoDB scan

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, amazon-dynamodb

I am building a sign up/log in system in an iOS app using swift. I have a DynamoDB table set up, and I can send and load data from that table. However, I've run into a problem when I try to scan the table. I'm using the scan to check and make sure the emails, usernames, and passwords are original. The scan function works and brings all the data down, but when I try to use the data like when I say:

```
let results = task.result as! AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput

                for r in results.items{

                    if (self.emailTextField.text == r.userEmail){

                        self.emailMessageLabel.hidden = false
                        self.emailTextField.text = nil

                    }
```

the whole function gets confused. Because what it does is checks to see if emailTextField is equal to any of the results, and even if it is once, all of the other times it's not. So it will say that the emailMessageLabel.hidden is true as many times as emailTextField is not equal to anything, and false the one time that it is. So essentially the answer is both true and false, and I can't use that data. How do I fix this? I've been trying to fix it for days. I'll attach all the code that I've been trying to use.

**Scan Function**

```
func verifyAndActivateAccount(expression : AWSDynamoDBScanExpression) {
    self.emailMessageLabel.hidden = true
    self.nameMessageLabel.hidden = true
    self.passwordMessageLabel.hidden = true
    let tableRow = DDBTableRow()
    let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()

    dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(DDBTableRow.self, expression: expression) .continueWithExecutor(BFExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(),
        withBlock: { (task:BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            if (task.error == nil) {
                let results = task.result as! AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput

                for r in results.items{

                    if (self.emailTextField.text == r.userEmail){

                        self.emailMessageLabel.hidden = false


                    }
                    if (self.nameTextField.text == r.UserID) {

                        self.nameMessageLabel.hidden = false


                    }
                    if (self.passwordTextField.text == r.userPassword){

                        self.passwordMessageLabel.hidden = false


                    }



                }



            }else{

                self.giveSignUpAlert("Scan didn't work.")

            }

            return nil

    })

}
```

**Button is Pressed**

```
@IBAction func storeRegisterInfo(sender: UIButton) {
    let exp = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    self.verifyAndActivateAccount(exp)
    //Check for original info
    let tableRow = DDBTableRow()
    tableRow?.UserID = self.nameTextField.text
    tableRow?.userEmail = self.emailTextField.text
    tableRow?.userPassword = self.passwordTextField.text

    let userEmail = emailTextField.text
    let userName = nameTextField.text
    let userPassword = passwordTextField.text
    let userConfirm = confirmTextField.text



    if userPassword != userConfirm {

        giveSignUpAlert("Your Passwords Don't Match!")

    }
    if (self.passwordTextField.text == self.confirmTextField.text) {
        if (userEmail.isEmpty || userName.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userConfirm.isEmpty){

            giveSignUpAlert("All Field Are Required")

        }else{

            self.insertDataIntoTable(tableRow)

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Define original. Do you mean that emails and usernames and passwords cannot be reused among different users? That may or may not make sense. It is possible that one person wants to make multiple users at the same email address. It is very possible that two or more people will choose the same password, so why require that passwords be unique? Don't you need to break out of your paginated scan once you find overlapping emails or usernames?

Comment: Yes I want to make it so that every username and email has never been used, but I'm willing to let the password be unoriginal. And I don't know what you mean by break out of my paginated scan.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you can use:

1. Use an abstract concept of user identifier as the Hash Key of your users table. Whenever you create a new user, first add an item keyed at the email address of the new user, with a username attribute. Next, add an item keyed at the username of the new user, where the entire user profile is kept. Because both usernames and email addresses are hash keys in this table, a conditional write with ConditionExpression=attribute_not_exists(user_identifier) on the email address PutItem and username PutItem call is enough to guarantee old records are not overwritten. This approach has an unlikely race condition in between the email item write and username item write. This approach also requires a restriction on usernames - usernames cannot contain the @ mark or otherwise look like an email address.
2. Have the base table keyed on username and a GSI projecting all attributes keyed on email address. When a new user signs up, do a Query on the GSI for a user keyed at the given email address and make sure no user used the email, then make sure the username is unique with attribute_not_exists(username) on the PutItem to the table.
3. Enable a DynamoDB Stream on your USERS table with view=NEW_IMAGE and attach a Lambda function to the stream that writes the email addresses of new users to a different table, EMAILS. To add a user, first GetItem on EMAILS table to make sure that the email does not exist, and then PutItem on USERS table with an attribute_not_exists condition.

Comment: I can query the table and get an empty value for UserID but for some reason I can't do an attribute_not_exists condition as you suggested. When I print the result of a query where I put a username that didn't exist it prints out "[ ]" I tried to say if results.items = nil then do something but that doesn't work. any suggestions?